# Matplotlib: Interior of shape in another colour

Tags: python, matplotlib

Consider the plot of the *pseudo-sphere* obtained with the following code (just the blue shape below)

```
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np

    '''
    ==========================================
    Ploting S^n_1
    '''

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(1))  
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

    r=1
    u=np.linspace(-2,2,200)
    v=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,60)
    [u,v]=np.meshgrid(u,v)

    a = 1
    b = 1
    c = 1

    x = a*np.cosh(u)*np.cos(v)
    y = b*np.cosh(u)*np.sin(v)
    z = c*np.sinh(u)

    ax.plot_surface(x, y, z,  rstride=4, cstride=4, color='#428bca')
    ax.set_axis_off()
    plt.show()
```

[image]

I find it not as easy as could be to spot the difference between the interior and exterior of the shape. For this reason I would like to have the interior in another colour. In any ideas how that could be done?

Comment: You could play around with `set_facecolor()` and `set_edgecolor()` but I expect it to only affect the blue patches and grey lines.

Comment: Do you want to make the surface semi-tranparent in order to see the interior?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Not necessarily, but I am open to any suggestion that looks more *readable* :) That being said what I initially had in mind was having two colours: one per side (interior/exterior).

Comment: For history, my answer was the previous accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying @Guimoute's suggestions, I came up with something slightly easier to read. Here is the only line modified in the above code

```
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z,  rstride=4, cstride=4, color='#428bca', edgecolor='#003366')
```

where I added the argument `edgecolor` in order to have more contrast between the grid and face of the shape. Here is the result: (I also changed the blue/green colour of the hyperbola to red)

[image]

**PS**

I won't (just yet) accept that as an answer in case someone else comes up with something.

Answer (score 1):

Since matplotlib 3D is not capable of doing much of real 3D operations. Simple trick is used here. The surface is split into 2 parts and drawn with different colors. Finally, viewing angle is set carefully to render the image.

Here is the working code (based on yours):

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(1))
fig.set_size_inches([8,8])
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

#r=1

# values for extents of meshes
begp = 0.25
endp = 1+begp
extp = endp+1

u = np.linspace(-2, 2, 200)
#v = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 60)
v = np.linspace(begp*np.pi, endp*np.pi, 30)
[u,v] = np.meshgrid(u,v)

u2 = np.linspace(-2, 2, 200)
v2 = np.linspace(endp*np.pi, extp*np.pi, 30)
[uu2, vv2] = np.meshgrid(u2, v2)

a = 1
b = 1
c = 1

# surface 1
x = a*np.cosh(u)*np.cos(v)
y = b*np.cosh(u)*np.sin(v)
z = c*np.sinh(u)

# surface 2
x2 = a*np.cosh(uu2)*np.cos(vv2)
y2 = b*np.cosh(uu2)*np.sin(vv2)
z2 = c*np.sinh(uu2)

# plot surface 1 in red / surface 2 in blue
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=4, cstride=4, color='red', edgecolor='gray')
ax.plot_surface(x2, y2, z2, rstride=4, cstride=4, color='blue', edgecolor='lightgray')

# set viewing angle + perspactive to get best image
ax.azim = 313   # z rotation (default=270)
ax.elev = 16    # x rotation (default=0)
ax.dist = 8    # zoom (define perspective)
ax.set_axis_off()
plt.show()
```

The generated image:

[image]